# RxJS: delaying incoming observables

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs, observable

I have a SnackbarComponent which is responsbile for displaying a Snackbar with informations for users. Notifications are coming from NotificationService to which I subscribe in my `SnackbarComponent`. Incoming messages are pushed to messages array and shifted from it after 3 seconds. In my html template I iterate over messages and display them.

```
export class SnackbarComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  private notificationSubscription: Subscription;
  messages: NotificationMessage[] = [];

  constructor(private notificationService: NotificationService) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.notificationSubscription = this.notificationService.notification$
      .subscribe(
        (message: NotificationMessage) => {
          this.messages.push(message);
          setTimeout(() => {
            this.messages.shift();
          }, 3000);
        }
      )
  }

  ngOnDestroy(): void {
    this.notificationSubscription.unsubscribe();
  }
```

The problem is, I'd like to display only 3 messages at a time and delay others (or display immediately if less than 3 messages currently).

I've got a working solution which looks like this:

```
private notificationSubscription: Subscription;
messages: NotificationMessage[] = [];
messagesQueue: NotificationMessage[] = [];


  ngOnInit() {
    this.notificationSubscription = this.notificationService.notification$
      .subscribe(
        (message: NotificationMessage) => {
          if (this.messages.length < 3) {
            this.messages.push(message);
            this.timeoutMessage();
          } else {
            this.messagesQueue.push(message);
          }
        }
      )
  }

  private timeoutMessage() {
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.messages.shift();
      if (this.messagesQueue.length > 0) {
        this.messages.push(this.messagesQueue.shift());
        this.timeoutMessage();
      }
    }, 3000);
  }
```

If there are 3 or messages, new messages are pushed to messagesQueue and in `timeoutMessage()` objects from `messagesQueue` are shifted to messages array.

But I don't find this solution elegant. Is there a RxJS way to somehow delay messages with some `pipe` operators?

Answer (score 3):

you can use **delay** operator or conditional delay **delayWhen** to delay based on a condition

```
import {delay} from 'rxjs/operators';

this.notificationService.notification$.pipe(
  delay(3000)
).subscribe();
```

example with **delayWhen**

```
this.notificationService.notification$.pipe(
  delayWhen(message => this.messages.length < 3 ? interval(0) : interval(3000))
).subscribe();
```

Comment: It delays every norification. If messages array length is less than 3, I don't want to delay them.

And consider this case: 3 notifications are coming at the same time, after 2500ms fourth notification is coming. 3 notifications will be shown and after 3000 ms they should disappear and 4th should be shown at 3000ms for another 3000ms, but 4th will be shown at 5500ms

Comment: take a look on conditional delay here https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/delayWhen

Comment: interval time would have to be calculated somehow, setting it to 3000 will cause problems with order, look at: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-feyqox

Answer (score 0):

You can use `BufferCount` operator to do it . It will emit values 3 at a time and i've added a second delay just to make sure .

```
import {bufferCount,delay } from 'rxjs/operators';

this.notificationService.notification$.pipe(
  bufferCount(3),delay(3000)
).subscribe();
```

Here is a stackblitz [example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wa3otm):

Comment: If only one notification comes, it won't be shown until 2 more come.

Comment: @mlemmy , it will show . You can try the stackblitz link I've shared .Try changing the observable values to 1 and check. It will emit it . BufferCount is only to group the values .

Comment: Please look at: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-169vb1
It shows what problem I have with this solution.
Also I don't like it forces me to have an array in subscribe